# tomcat8w.exe not in 'notification area' / and sometimes is in 'notification area'

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, tomcat

Using Java8/64 and Tomcat8/64 on Windows Server 2008 R2.
On one server, the 'tomcat8w.exe' shows up in the notification area, and I can use it from there to start/stop/configure.  On two other exact same machines, it does *not* show up in the 'notification area'.  I have to find it (tomcat8w.exe) in tomcat's bin directory to start it, and then I can use it to start/stop/configure.

Yes, I do know I can start/stop it in 'Services'.  Not what I want to do.

I wish to have tomcat8w.exe in the 'notification area'.  What did I do wrong?  How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple. Create a shortcut and add it to your start menu.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain yourself. The OP state that manually starting the. Exe fix the problem. The monitor program is not a service

Comment: Sometimes questions have a simple answer. To me it was ok (I was not the down). But careful answers have a much better chance for survival and for upvotes.

Comment: While I agree that this would make the 'tomcat8w.exe' start automatically, ( and not a bad suggestion at that if it would, in turn, start tomcat ), I would prefer that the 'tomcat8w.exe' be in the 'notification area', like it did in my first install.  I'm really not quite sure what it means for something to be in the 'notification area', but my thought was that it would have to be a service.  I did look at the tomcat service on the machine where the 'notification area' is used, and the path to executable is the actual tomcat .exe, not the 'tomcat8w.exe'.  I'm so confused.

Comment: @WilliamGraham Check in the registry of the server that work (regedit.exe) there: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx). Note any difference.

Comment: @WilliamGraham The icon there are usually a service that can interact with the desktop or a small program that load to monitor the service. Why I asked you to check the registry. Some reference: (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html) Tomcat7w is a GUI application for monitoring and configuring Tomcat services.  (//MS//
Monitor service Put the icon in the system tray)

Comment: Sigh.  Okay, this was not a good first question on ServerFault.  Kudos to yagmoth555 for answering the question.  I've been playing with this on and off since yesterday.  In all 3 servers mentioned, the 'notification area' was set to show all notification icons and statuses.  However, after checking the 2 previously recalcitrant machines, I find they now show the 'tomcat8w.exe' icon in the 'notification area'.  I did not change anything since asking this question.  I did a normal install, nothing unusual, but it took those notifs 24 hours to show up. Wow. Any comments about that?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me just now on a Windows Server 2012. After I clicked Exit in the little manager application in the System Tray, it disappeared and did not come back. I had to open C:\Project\Tomcat\Bin\Tomcat8w.exe to see the configuration panel, and start stop buttons.

Later I looked for Monitor Tomcat by searching the Blue Screen of Swipe (because this version acts like Windows 8) and found a shortcut in the directory:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Apache Tomcat 8.0 Tomcat8\
```

The short cut titled "Monitor Tomcat" is pointing to C:\Project\Tomcat\Bin\Tomcat8w.exe.

When I clicked on that shortcut, there was UAC prompt and next tomcat8 tool was again in the system tray having Start, or Stop and Configure links.